# Smooth algebraic plane curves are open in Zariski

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry, projective-space, plane-curves

Homogeneus polynomials of degree n can be seen as points of $K^m\setminus\{0\}$. It's natural seeing plane algebraic curves of degree n as points of the projective space. I was told that smooth curves are open in Zariski, but I wasn't able to prove it.

Can anyone prove it?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You can see the general homogeneus polynomials with 3 variables of degree 2 as ax^2+bxy+cxz+dy^2+eyz+fz^2 (a curve of degree 2 is a point in the 5-dimensional projective space). A professor told me that the set polynomials that defines smooth curves is open in the Zariski topology. I don't know how to be more clear, can you please explain what else should I clarify? I tried to prove it but I have no idea of how to do it (i thought of resultant but i couldn't come up with anything)